# Add or remove events into a StreamInsight window

Tags: esper, streaminsight

Is there a way to retain all events and just add or delete events as desired in StreamInsight? In Esper there is a method called keepall() witch can be applied on a window. This method keeps all incoming events and you can have different queries for inserting events in the window or deleting them.

I tried using `Hopping`, `Snaphot`, `Tumbling` and `Count Window` in StreamInsight, but none of them has the above mentioned functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like you are asking about with a window using a User-Defined Operator. Here's a link to the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842720(v=sql.111).aspx

If you want to interact with the events in a procedural way without a window then take a look at User-Defined Stream Operators. The docs for that are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290514(v=sql.111).aspx

With more detail about what you are trying to accomplish, I can give you a better answer.